# How to get fast gold in clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I really need some gold fast. I want to get the clan castle. I am at TH3 if you are wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Attack goblins to get more gold or you can also attack others(assuming you have no shield or are prepared to sacrifice yours) or boost up your resource collectors...it uses gems and is not recommended if you don't have 3 builder's hut(lvl 5 gold mine or elixr collector required to boost. No boost for lower lvls).